# Can I disable my touchscreen when playing Octodad?

Tags: octodad-dadliest-catch

When playing Octodad, I'm having trouble getting the computer to accept input from anything other than the touch screen. I can move my arms, but can't grab anything with the buttons. All of the tutorial screens come up with instructions for playing the game with the touch screen. How can I force the input to be the Xbox controller I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to do this with my old touchscreen computer, you can open device manager (just search installed apps for "Device manager") and try to disable your touch screen.

Just check the "Mice and other pointing devices" and "Human Interface Devices" sections and look for anything that has "touch screen" at its name, right click it and click disable (**NOT UNINSTALL**), and when you are done with the game, just reenable it from the same place...

It should look like this:

[image: Picture from Device Manager]
*Image courtesy PCWorld.*